# Progressbar on Pandas-datareader?

Tags: progress-bar, pandas-datareader

Is it possible to wrap `df = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start, end)` inside a progressbar? It takes about 20 mins but it would it be possible to see the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `tqdm`. Here is a link [Click here](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)

This would work on tickers to see how many variables have been completed.